# How to get rid of the file extensions in the output of list.files in R

Tags: r

output of command `list.files("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Read")` is

```
[1] "1.jpg"           "2.jpg"           "3.jpg"           "Untitled4-1.jpg" "Untitled4-2.jpg" "Untitled4-3.jpg"
```

How do I get an output `"1" "2" "3" "Untitled4-1" "Untitled4-2"`

Comment: `tools::file_path_sans_ext(list.files("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Read"))`

Comment: In base R you can remove the extensions with a regular expression using `sub` : `sub("(^.*)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", list.files("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Read"))`